# Clear Blood Vessel Segmentation in 3D image using VTK

Tags: visual-studio, vtk, image-segmentation, itk

I am using vtk for segmenting blood vessels.
I have two dicom image sets,one has normal CT images and the other has CT with MIP(Maximum Intensity Projection).
So i subtracted the two series and gave that result to the input of `vtkMarchingCubes`.But my segmented image is showing only less details.I have attached what i got in the picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V66nN.png

I tried using filters but no use

I need to get even the thin vessels.How is it possible using only VTK?
If not How is it possible in ITK.

If my question is not clear kindly inform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ITK, you could use [vesselness](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Nonunit/Review/SegmentBloodVesselsWithMultiScaleHessianBasedMeasure/Documentation.html) filter to enhance the vessels. That should make them easier to extract.

Comment: Can you tell how to copy an itk variable in to a vtk variable.Because from your provided link,i need to copy the output of itk variable `multiScaleEnhancementFilter` and need to give as input to vtkExtractVOI?

Comment: without using `ItkVtkGlue`is it possible to copy itk to vtk?

Comment: You can use `vtkImageImport` and get the pointer from `itkImage->GetBufferPointer()`.

Comment: thanks  i will try it. I also need to give`vtkImageMathematics`variable to the input of `itk::MultiScaleHessianBasedMeasureImageFilter`is that possible without `ItkVtkGlue`?

Comment: You can do the inverse process there: get the output into `vtkImageData`, call its `GetScalarPointer()` and pass that into `itk::ImportImageFilter`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use [3D Slicer](https://www.slicer.org/) and then download `VMTKVesselEnhancement` for it and to identify tubular shapes in your 3D images and then using segmentation methods to extract the 3D surfaces of the blood vessel.